# Why does my page look different in design than at run-time?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm studying HTML/CSS and doing a single-page project using WebStorm and Chrome. Normally I test the way my page running Chrome in WebStorm which results in opening http://localhost:63342/ in my browser address line.

After I finished my project I closed WebStorm and ran it again in Chrome, but this time I open it by clicking on the shortcut on my desktop.

To my surprise, the way the page looks was different from the one that I saw when I opened Chrome through WebStorm.

The question is: Why so? It's the same HTML/CSS code, the same browser.

[image: Chrome only]
[image: Chrome through WebStorm]

Comment: Are you sure it's the same version of Chrome?

Comment: Have you got all code in one file ?

Comment: We could help you more if you post your html & css. It may be that you have a path or two incorrect.

Comment: The answer too both questions is yes, I guess.

1) WebStorm uses my Chrome. Even if I assume that it has its own one, when I tried running FireFox, which I don't have on my computer, it didn't open it, thus it uses my Chrome and I have only one version of it.

2) Well, technically, my style is in style.css file which is in the same folder as the html one. All the alignments and paddings are kept, it's just the button design and <select> design that are different.

Comment: @ Stuart

I tried to post it but it's too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://brackets.io/ as an alternative. It has a similar feature called  "live preview".

It seems that there is no style applied to your page. If you have your css in a separate file, my guess is that WebStorm doesn't locate your CSS file or you are not referencing it correctly in your html. Try looking at the "Sources" tab from the Chrome Developer Tools (F18) and see if it loaded the .css file.

[image: PrintScreen from Chrome Sources]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it had something to do with the page scale. When I press cmd and + and the page zooms in, it gets a slightly different look.